# Popup on hover flickers when over link (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, css, popup, hover, flicker

I managed to write experiment with the following code and it works more or less. There should be a link to open a popup when you hover on the link, and dims the other links.

https://jsfiddle.net/sigug/owfknbd6/49/

The issue now is that when the popup is above the link (which is not a problem), it starts to flicker probably because the "hover" function gets "confused" or whatever. How to fix this?

```
<div class="container">
 <a data-target="boxid1" class="link-box"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x65"></a>
</div>
<div class="container">
 <a data-target="boxid2" class="link-box"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x65"></a>
</div>
<div class="container">
 <a data-target="boxid3" class="link-box"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x65"></a>
</div>


<div id="boxid1" class="modal-box">
 Content Box 1
</div>
<div  id="boxid2" class="modal-box">
 Content Box 2
</div>
<div  id="boxid3" class="modal-box">
 Content Box 3
</div>
```

```
.container { background: black; color: white; padding: 50px; float: left; border: 1px solid red; margin: 5px; text-align: center; }
.modal-box { display: none; position: absolute; top: 50%;   left: 50%; transform:translate(-50%,-50%); background: blue; color: white; padding: 25px; width: 250px; height: 200px; }
.dim { opacity: 0.3; }
```

```
$(function(){

    $('.link-box').hover(function(e){
    var $parent=$(this).closest('.container');  
            $('.container').not($parent).addClass('dim');
      $('#'+$(this).attr('data-target')).show();},
      
          function(e) {
            var $parent=$(this).closest('.container');  
            $('.container').not($parent).removeClass('dim');
                 $('#'+$(this).attr('data-target')).hide();
            }
  );

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the problem is the hover when cusor goes over the popup. If you move the popup inside the anchor link-box solve the problem.

```js
$(function(){

    $('.link-box').hover(function(e){
    var $parent=$(this).closest('.container');  
            $('.container').not($parent).addClass('dim');
      $('#'+$(this).attr('data-target')).show();},
      
          function(e) {
            var $parent=$(this).closest('.container');  
            $('.container').not($parent).removeClass('dim');
                 $('#'+$(this).attr('data-target')).hide();
            }
  );

});
```

```css
.container {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 50px;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
.modal-box {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  padding: 25px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 200px;
  z-index: 10;
 }
.dim {
  opacity: 0.3;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
 <a data-target="boxid1" class="link-box"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x65">
 <div id="boxid1" class="modal-box">
 Content Box 1
</div>
 </a>
</div>
<div class="container">
 <a data-target="boxid2" class="link-box"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x65">
 <div  id="boxid2" class="modal-box">
 Content Box 2
</div>
 </a>
</div>
<div class="container">
 <a data-target="boxid3" class="link-box"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x65">
 <div  id="boxid3" class="modal-box">
 Content Box 3
</div>
 </a>
</div>
```

Comment: <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
please add jquery link in this

Comment: Thank you! And how would I mix this with a "mobile" solution, so you can click on the items.
I have this code

$(function(){

 $('.link-box').click(function(e){
  var $parent=$(this).closest('.about-profile');  
  $('.about-profile').not($parent).toggleClass('dim');
  $('#'+$(this).attr('data-target')).toggle();
 });

 
$('html').click(function() {
   $('#modal-box').hide(); 
});

$('.about-profile').click(function(event){
     event.stopPropagation();
});

});